# How to start with Classes in c++

Tags: c++, class, object

I at classes and objects of C++, where i am facing difficulties to understand the concept of deceleration of a class, for which i have make a little program which is not compiling, anybody will guide me?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass{
    friend increment(myClass, int);
  private:
    int topSecret;
  public:
    myClass(){
        topSecret = 100;
    }
    void display(){
        cout<<"The value of top Secter is"<<topSecret;
    }
  };

   void increment(myClass A, int i){
       A.topSecret += i;
   }

   int main() {
     myClass x;
     x.display();
     increment(x,10);
     x.display();

     }
```

Comment: `friend void increment(myClass, int);` << **void**

Comment: is it necessary to declare return type of friend function? @user657267

Comment: You should write a `getter()` and a `setter()` function to access your private member `topSecret`.

Comment: @Bilal, all functions must have a type, atleast a void

Comment: why don't you add a deconstructor too? Aslo you do realize the function parameter int i is completely useless.

Comment: @ArunA.S: all functions... except constructors and destructors.  @Bilal: you probably want increment to be `void increment(myClass& A, int i) ...`: the `&` means the function uses a reference to the caller's `myClass` object, so the `+=` actually operates on `main()`'s `x` object.  Otherwise `increment` makes a copy of `x` when it starts running, modifies the copy, and throws it away when it returns.

Comment: Yes i know constructor and destructors don't have return types. But if i add destructor in this program, it does not pass the incremented value that i have declared in main() function.

Comment: Forgot about them. Thanks for notifying me @Tony D

Comment: @IrrationalPerson: a destructor isn't needed here... there are no non-automatic (i.e. off-stack) resources to release when a `myClass` object goes out of scope or is `delete`d.  Could be used for some logging to help show what's happening though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
friend increment(myClass, int);
```

to

```
friend void increment(myClass &, int);
```

That should fix your compilation errors.

---

To modify the original object passed to a function, declare the function to take a reference:

```
void increment(myClass A, int i){
```

to

```
void increment(myClass &A, int i){
```

Comment: Thanks for it, but void increment function still didn't passing its definition... I mean i am still don't seeing the incremented value.. by increment(x,10); x.display();

Answer (score 2):

Arun's answer shows you how to fix your compilation error, but this is not how you should design a class. Defining non-member friend functions to access your internal data will often lead to maintenance issues and bugs. You would be better off either declaring `increment` as a public member function, or defining getter and setters for your class:

```
class myClass{
private:
    int topSecret;
public:
    //use initialization list instead of setting in constructor body
    myClass() : topSecret(100) {}

    //getter, note the const
    int GetTopSecret() const { return topSecret; }
    //setter, non-const
    void SetTopSecret(int x) { topSecret = x; }

    //member version
    void increment (int i) { topSecret += i; }
};

//non-member version with setter
//note the reference param, you were missing this
void increment(myClass &A, int i){
    A.SetTopSecret(A.GetTopSecret() + i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add void bebore increment in class definition as Arun A.S said.
2. You can't change A.topSecret in increment function because you take object by value, so you just change temporary object, use instead     void increment(myClass &A, int i)